# Regular Expression question Visual Studio

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I'm wanting to replace all references to a resource file in my C# code.

An example is a page that contains several references such as:

```
Resources.Global.Firstname  
Resources.Global.Surname
```

I'd like the regular expression to find all of these (they could end either with a `;` or a `)`).

Total beginner with regular expressions, so any advice here would be gratefully received.

Comment: Why do you need a regular expression? You can't just right click on the property definition and choose 'Find all references'?

Comment: Do you mean in the visual studio search and replace dialog box?

Comment: Would Refactor->Rename work in your case?

Comment: There are about 800 pages, each containing potentially 1,100 different references to a resource so rather than go through each one manually it would be easier to write an app that replaces them.

Comment: Refactoring won't work since he's talking about the consuming code side changing how they're getting the data. He's not talking about renaming one property or method to another; see the comment to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the Find and Replace window in Visual Studio.

1. Press Ctrl-H to open the window.
2. Put `Resources\.Global\.{[^,) ;]+}` in the "Find what:" text box.
3. Put `GetStringValue("\1")` in the "Replace with:" text box.
4. Make sure the "Look in:" dropdown is set to the scope you want to search
5. Expand the Find options subpanel.
6. Check the box next to "Use:" and make sure that "Regular expressions" is selected.

#### What this is doing:

The first regular expression will find anything that starts with `Resources.Global.` and capture whatever is after it until it finds a space, a comma, a close paren, or a semi-colon.

The second one replaces the entire text that was found with `GetStringValue("")` and puts the captured text inside the quotes in the parentheses.

Comment: Brilliant, never knew you could do that. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do CTRL+H (quick find and replace) and search on the actual terms rather than the regex pattern?  What are you trying to rename from and to?

UPDATE
The pattern to match would be something like: Resources.Global.([^};]+)

Replace pattern would be GetStringValue("\1")

Comment: Basically, each reference (Resource.Global.*) needs to be replaced with GetStringValue("*") as we are moving from resource files to a database solution.

Comment: ok, so in  your example, the call would go from (for example):  Resources.Global.Firstname to GetStringValue("Firstname")?

Comment: That's exactly right. There are approx 1,100 different resource entries in the global resource so going through everyone and renaming them is a cumbersome process. The other way would be to create a utility that would match a regex, and replace the text with the GetStringValue("*")

Comment: k, updated my answer for you.  Note I left the CTRL+H comment there b/c you can apply regex replaces using the quick replace dialog in VS.

Comment: wouldn't you need some quantifier inside of the capturing group?

Comment: Doh! I didn't see your update. You'll need to change the $1 to a \1 for it to work in Visual Studio though and you don't need to escape the quotes in the replace pattern and you need to use curly braces instead of parentheses to capture the text.

Comment: Ya, Visual Studio regular expressions are slightly different for some reason.  You can find instructions on how to use them and how they're different [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: @dontangg> thanks, been there but just missed that "feature". Been a while since I've had to use the VS regex vice regex in C# too.

Answer (score 0):

As Blazes said, in the scenario you mentioned, Refactoring is the actual answer. If you just want to see them, right click on the definition and select Find all references. If you want to change it, just make the changes and then press ctrl+shift+F11, a context menu appears which gives you the chance to rename all references.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression:

```
(Resources\.Global\.[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*[;\)])
```

will find only the last two lines out of the following tested lines:

```
Resources.Global.Firstname  
Resources.Global.Surname
Resources.Global.Firstname;  
Resources.Global.Surname)
```

used code to verify:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(Resources\.Global\.[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*[;\)])");
MatchCollection mc = regex.Matches("Resources.Global.Firstname\n" + 
    "Resources.Global.Surname" + 
    "Resources.Global.Firstname;" + 
    "Resources.Global.Surname)");

foreach (Match match in mc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].ToString());
}
```

This software might help you:

[Rad Software Regular Expression Designer](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/regexlearnsyntax.aspx)

Comment: your regex could fail in some cases, resource names can have non-letter characters and don't have to start w/ a capital.

Comment: @Paul you're right, but (at least for me) that was not clear from his original question. In fact, it wasn't even clear that he wants to refactor things. My answer has become pretty much obsolete by this turn of events